# undefined is not an object error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a route to a screen by pressing a button in a side menu using react navigation. When I try to implement it, I get the following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.user.Range')

The error flags, point something wrong in here:

```
RangeValues: this.props.user.Range
```

The rest of the components I am trying to navigate to are here:

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react'
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      Text,
      Switch,
    } from 'react-native'

    import Slider from 'react-native-multislider'

    export default class Profile extends Component {
       state = {
        RangeValues: this.props.user.Range,
        distanceValue: [this.props.user.distance]
      }
    render() {
        const {name, work, id} = this.props.user
        const {RangeValues, distanceValue} = this.state
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.profile}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>{name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.label}>
              <Text>Distance</Text>
              <Text style={{color:'darkgrey'}}>{distanceValue}km</Text>
            </View>
            <Slider
              min={1}
              max={100}
              values={distanceValue}
              onValuesChange={val => this.setState({distanceValue:val})}
              onValuesChangeFinish={val => this.updateUser('distance', val[0])}
            />
            <View style={styles.label}>
              <Text>Age Range</Text>
              <Text style={{color:'darkgrey'}}>{ageRangeValues.join('-')}</Text>
            </View>
            <Slider
              min={1}
              max={200}
              values={RangeValues}
              onValuesChange={val => this.setState({RangeValues:val})}
              onValuesChangeFinish={val => this.updateUser('Range', val)}
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

I want to navigate from a button in a drawer using stack navigator, my routing is as follows:

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import React from 'react'; 
import Home from './screens/home';
import Login from './screens/login';
import Profile from './screens/profile';

const RouteConfigs = {
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Profile: { screen: Profile },
};

const StackNavigatorConfig = {
  headerMode: 'none',
}

export default StackNavigator(RouteConfigs, StackNavigatorConfig)
```

Where I am trying to navigate from is the Home screen component. The function I have used for this within the Home component is:

```
() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { user: this.state.user })
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error in order for me to navigate from the home component to the profile component?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind your props from constructor :

```
export class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if (!this.state) { 
      this.state = {
        data: props.myData
      }
    }

    render() {DO THE JOB HERE}
  }
}
```

Then you can access to `this.state` instead of `state`

For more explanations, `props` are not yet available since the constructor has not pass. See Component doc : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: What if you `console.log` props in the constructor ?

Comment: When I do that, I get [object Object]. It says the data is undefined, I'm just not sure how or where to define it?

Comment: I don't understand which is undefined et which is [object Object] ?
Basically you should use `console.log("descriptor", myObject);` to see object (import point is the comma instead of + before myObject). Then you can inspect the Obect with chrome:inspect for android (and I don't remember for iOS ...)

Comment: The error says undefined is not an object which I though is this.state. When I console logged props I got [object Object]